# How to sum the products of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, product

New to python trying to code a product summation formula that would iterate through a pandas dataframe. Any tips? Sorry if this question has already been asked.

```
result = []
i = 0
while i < len(r):
    np.prod([1*(1+r)])
    result.append(r[i])
    i += 1
print(result)
```

This is the code I came up with if anybody has a better way of doing please let me know.
`r` is my pandas dataframe. When I run this code all I get is infinite and it's not close to the formula I actually like to put that data through

The formula I'm trying to implement is

[image: the formula I'm trying to implement]

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful. Are you trying to sum each column? Or every element of the DataFrame?

Comment: Iterating over a dataframe will iterate over the column names.

Comment: trying to sum each column. thanks for the help guys

Comment: So you want to end up with one number for each column that is the result of multiplying all the contents of the column together, and them sum those numbers?

Comment: I just want to sum each column with the above formula

Comment: I'm confused that equation is the product notation yet you want a sum?

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have put product summation making the edit now

Comment: Based on your equation every value in the column get + 1 then product am I right?

Comment: Why is there a 1x in the formula?

Comment: IDK didn't write was just asked to code it

Comment: Yeah resident I'm pretty sure you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your equation use  [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`numpy.prod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html)

```
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['B'] = [4, 5, 6]

result = (df + 1).apply(lambda x: np.prod(x))
result

A     24
B    210
dtype: int64
```